# How to get data from core_config_data table in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cron, core-config-data, data

I have created a cron and in that i want to get some values from **core_config_data** table in my Cron File.

My Cron file is :

```
<?php

 namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Cron;

 use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action;

 class Customcron
 {  
private $productAction;
protected $_logger;
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
private $_objectManager;

public function __construct(
    Action $productAction,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
) {
    $this->productAction = $productAction;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
}

public function execute(){

    $config = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('section/group/field');
    $values = (array)json_decode($config, true);

    $attributes = [
        'status' => 2,
        'price' => '10.70'
    ];
    $productIds = ['1'];
    $storeId = 0;
    $this->productAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributes, $storeId);
}
}
```

My controller index file is :

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

  class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;
private $scopeConfig;
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
){
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    return parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function execute()
{   
    $product_ids = [];
    $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('am_shipping/prices/add_item');
    $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
    foreach ($productCollection as $key => $value) {
        $product_ids[] = $value->getId();
    }
    print_r($product_ids);
    print_r($configValue);die('aaaa');
    //return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
}
```

**It shows me the error  Type Error occurred when creating object: Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor**

Comment: what your question? Question has it answer. Please ask a clear question

Comment: I update answer please check.

Comment: I update new answer again, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do code like this :

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;
private $scopeConfig;
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
){
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{   
    $product_ids = [];
    $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('am_shipping/prices/add_item');
    $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
    foreach ($productCollection as $key => $value) {
        $product_ids[] = $value->getId();
    }
    print_r($product_ids);
    print_r($configValue);die('aaaa');
    //return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
}
```

Comment: I have updated my controller index file which gives me this error  Type Error occurred when creating object: Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor will you please help @Dhiren

Comment: I update answer please check.

Comment: Updated your file on di:compile command it shows Errors during compilation:
 Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index
  Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $data. File: /var/www/html/reg-dealers/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php
Total Errors Count: 1
 this error @Dhiren

Comment: I update code, please check that one.

Comment: Thanks Yes it works with removing the data parameter thanks for your response. but there is an issue rearding i have applied a condition to show only disabled product ids with this $productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false); but it shows all product's id's will you please help.

Comment: Can you raised seprate question for that one, so other in community also hep you into that one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetion done that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320393/how-to-get-only-disabled-product-in-magento-2-controller @Dhiren

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace VendorMagento\ModuleName\Cron;

Class Example
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
         $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('config/to/path');
    }
}
```

**Reference file:** vendor/magento/module-catalog/Cron/DeleteOutdatedPriceValues.php

> It shows me the error Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor

To resolve above error please run the following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I have updated my controller index file which gives me this error  Type Error occurred when creating object: Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor will you please help @Pratik

Comment: @Prits please cheki Update ans

Comment: on di:compile it shows Errors during compilation:
 Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index
  Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $data. File: /var/www/html/reg-dealers/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php
Total Errors Count: 1
this error.

Comment: Please remove $data from this code: return parent::__construct($context, $data); and try again.

Comment: Thanks it works i have applied a condition to show only disabled product ids with this $productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false); but it shows all product will you please help @PratikOza

Comment: Refer to the [link](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/6167/2)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inject this below class in your construct :

```
protected $scopeInterface;

public function __construct(
     ...
     \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeInterface,
     ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->scopeInterface = $scopeInterface;
    ...
}
```

And then, use this below line to get value from core config table :

```
$configValue = $this->scopeInterface->getValue('section/group/field',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Now, Remove generated folder and clean cache.

[Reference](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-get-store-config-value-in-magento-2/)

Comment: rohan do you have good hands on js i need some help regarding js here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320372/magento-javascript-timer-not-working