# How to get only disabled product in Magento 2 Controller?

Tags: magento2, product, controllers, disabled-products

How to get only disabled product In Controller I have getting all the products

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;
private $scopeConfig;
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
private $productAction;

public function __construct(
Action $productAction,
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
){
$this->productAction = $productAction;
$this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
$this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{   
$product_ids = [];

$onlydisproduct = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$onlydisproduct->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$onlydisproduct->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
foreach ($onlydisproduct as $key => $value) {
    $product_ids[] = $value->getId();
}
//print_r($product_ids);




die('aaaa');
//return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
}
```

Product Screenshot

[image]
**I am applying $onlydisproduct->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false); but still getting all products.**

Comment: what's your magento version?

Comment: do you want disable product or out of stock product?

Comment: If you need disabled you bneed that : `->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED)`

Comment: My magento version Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1 @RohanHapani

Comment: I want Disabled  Product @DhirenVasoya

Comment: I Post answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this below code in your controller and cache clean :

```
        $product_ids = [];
        $onlydisproduct = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
        foreach ($onlydisproduct as $key => $value) {
            $product_ids[] = $value->getId();
        }
        echo "<pre/>";
        print_r($product_ids);
        exit;
```

Comment: It gives me an empty array @Rohan

Comment: Did you get product collection? or have you disabled products in your product list?

Comment: How do i check for product collection on var_dump it gives me Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted @Rohan

Comment: print_r($onlydisproduct->getData()); just do it.

Comment: Did you get collection? @Prits

Comment: I have figured out the issue the Saleable quantity for Disabled product showing Default Stock: 0 so it doesn't show in array and why it becomes 0 my main stock is like 400 for all disabled product it shows 0 why is that is that a bug in syatem I have attached a screehshot will you please check. @Rohan

Comment: will you tell me with this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320441/saleable-quantity-showing-0-quantity-in-grid-in-magento-ver-2-3-5-p1 @Rohan

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code like this one :

```
$onlydisproduct = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$onlydisproduct->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$onlydisproduct->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

Comment: It gives me an empty array @Dhiren

Comment: Kindly check that you have some disable product into system.

Comment: Yes i have disabled product in my system @Dhiren

Comment: Then above code must work, have you check by caching and indexing commands.

Comment: Flushed all cached and indexer done but still no success@Dhiren

Comment: have you share any screenshot that, you have disable product into your system.

Comment: I have figured out the issue the Saleable quantity for Disabled product showing  Default Stock: 0 so it doesn't show in array and why it becomes 0 my main stock is like 400 for all disabled product it shows 0 why is that is that a bug in syatem I have attached a screehshot will you please check.@Dhiren

Comment: will you help me with this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320441/saleable-quantity-showing-0-quantity-in-grid-in-magento-ver-2-3-5-p1 @Dhiren

Comment: Have you got anything it would be really help full @Dhiren